# MYSQL Value Difference optimization

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

Hallo guys,

I'm running a very large database (ATM like >5 Million datasets). My database stores custom generated numbers (which and how they compose doesn't really matters here) and the corresponding date to this one. In addition there is a ID stored for every product (means one product can have multiple entries for different dates in my database -> primary key is divided). Now I want to `SELECT` those top 10 ID's which got the largest difference in theire numbers in the last two days. Currently I tried to achieve this using JOINS but since I got that much datasets this way is far to slow. How could I speed up the whole operation?

```
SELECT 
  d1.place,d2.place,d1.ID 
FROM 
  daily 
INNER JOIN 
  daily AS d1 ON d1.date = CURDATE() 
INNER JOIN 
  daily as d2 ON d2.date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
ORDER BY 
  d2.code-d1.code LIMIT 10
```

EDIT: Thats how my structure looks like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily` (
 `ID` bigint(40) NOT NULL,
 `source` char(20) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cc` char(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`source`,`date`,`cc`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thats the output of the `Explain` Statement

```
    id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  d1  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    5150350 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  d2  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   mytable.d1.ID   52  Using where
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT
  d1.ID, d1.place, d2.place
FROM
  daily AS d1
CROSS JOIN
  daily AS d2
USING (ID)
WHERE
  d1.date = CURDATE()
  AND d2.date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY
  d2.code - d1.code DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

---

Some thoughts about your table structure.

```
`ID` bigint(40) NOT NULL,
```

Why BIGINT? You would need to be doing 136 inserts/s 24h a day, 7 days a week for a year to exhaust the range of INT. And before you get halfway there, your application will probably need a professional DBA anyway. 
Remember, Smaller primary index leads to fater lookups - which brings us to:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`source`,`date`,`cc`)
```

Why? A single column PK on `ID` column should be enough. If you need indexes on other columns, create additional indexes (and to it wisely). As it is, you basically have a covering index for entire table... which is like having entire table in the index.

Last but not least: where is `place` column? You've used it in your query (and then I in mine), but it's nowhere to be seen?

Proposed table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `daily` (
 `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,  --usually AUTO_INCREMENT is used as well,
 `source` char(20) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cc` char(2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `ID_date` (`ID`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Without knowing your table structure? No way. In fact I don't even know if this does what you want ;P

Comment: Thats what my structure looks like :) `daily

Feld Typ Null Standard Kommentare
ID bigint(40) Nein     
source char(20) Nein     
date date Nein     
code int(11) Nein     
cc char(2) Nein    `

Comment: Please put entire table structure (with indexes) in your question. You can edit it. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE daily` and post the output.

Comment: done, i inserted the output from the export function as good as i coild

Comment: I cant't auto-increment because I'm kinda scraping the ID so it's not mine which means there is no possibility to use this feature

Comment: That explains why you're not using it, but it shouldn't affect performance anyway. I was just curious about it.

Comment: So you think thats the most efficient way out there ? :(

Comment: With improved indexes I proposed it should perform pretty well. You could use `EXPLAIN` to show us how it's performing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

Comment: @Tim Specht: Was the EXPLAIN run after changes to indexes I suggested, or does the table still have only this monstrous primary key?

Comment: I didn't made any changes to structure

Comment: I see. Well, as expected the query does not use indexes efficiently, because the only index you have is pretty much useless.

Comment: At least create a compund index on (`ID`,`date`) columns.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "compound"? ;)

Comment: A compnd index is an index created on two or more columns (as oppsed to single-column indexes). In your case query for that would be: `ALTER TABLE daily ADD KEY ID_date (ID,date)`. This might take a while in large dataset. After you add this index try EXPLAIN again.

Comment: But I need more than that two to identify one dataset, how has it any use for me then?

Comment: Please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html